# how can i use if else if condtion with a loop in searching sorting in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

How to use `if else` condition in searching (only using `one loop` and `if else if condition`) if array is already given e.g {12,13,14,15,16}
if user input 13 so it show *it found* and if user input 20 it shows *not found*.

My try :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/** * * @author Waseem */
public class Sear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        b = a.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
            if (b == index[i]) {
                System.out.println("found");
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println(index[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Waseem
 */
public class Sear {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         int index []={12,13,14,15,16} ;
         
  
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number");
b = a.next();

for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i ++)
{                       
  if (b == index[i])
     {
        System.out.println("found");
        break;
     }
else
    

System.out.println(index[i]);

Comment: This is called a linear search. I suggest you google it.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Davide
 */
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 16};

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        int b = a.nextInt();

        // one if and else
        if (find(index, 0, b)) {
            System.out.println("Number Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number not Found!!!");
        }
    }

    // one loop
    public static boolean find(int[] array, int index, int value) {
        return index < array.length && (array[index] == value || find(array, ++index, value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method has correct logic implemented!I am unsure why are you printing the array values if the user-entered element doesn't match array element...There is no need! Also,to print **NOT FOUND**,you need to have a variable set for that purpose,say `flag` variable of type `boolean` in my code!

Also,what you're missing is end-braces to close the loop,main() and the class. We always have a corresponding closing brace for each respective opening brace!

try this :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Waseem
 */
public class Sear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
        boolean flag = false;

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        int b = a.nextInt();

        for (int i : index) {
            if (flag = b == i) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(i);  // No need for this,but,even then this is fine!
            }
        }  // to close for-loop

        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("Number Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number not Found!!!");
        }
    }  // to close main() method
}  /// to close class Sear
```

Comment: You do not need a flag. The search should be moved to procedure and the output should depend on the search result. For example: public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        System.out.println(indexOf(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(), new int[]{12, 13, 14, 15, 16}) > 0 ? "found" : "not found");
        
    }

    public static int indexOf(int value, int... array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if(array[i] == i) return i;
        return -1;
    }

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have in your code is that you do not have declared what a type of next is.

When you call

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number"); 
b = a.next();
```

Method Scanner#next() by documentation result with a `String` type.

When you call `b == index[i]`, you try to compare the references with value. That is not allowed operation and you will get a compile error.

To read a integer from [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) use method `nextInt()`, then your program should run.

Regarding the algorithm, whenever you used a brake to control logic of your program should be a hint that this part should be moved to separate method.

Your problem can be divided in two like:

1. Find the number in array
2. Display message according to result in step one.

First we will have to write a method that will search an int in arrays of ints.

```
static int indexOf(int value, int[] values) {

   for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
      if(value == values[i]) return i;

   return -1;

}
```

The logic is simple, if a value is found then result with it index if not then result -1.

Now we can apply this method in the logic of our program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the a integer:");
        int value = inputReader.nextInt();

        int position = indexOf(value, index);

        if(position > 0) {
          System.out.println("found");
        } else {
          System.out.println("not found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got one for-each loop and one if statement

```
public String findInArray(int[] arrValues, int userInput){
    for(int element : arrValues) {
        if(element == userInput) {
            return "it found";
        } 
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ifelse {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] a={12,13,14,15,16};
int b;

for(int i=1;i<=a.length;i++)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input Number");
b = input.nextInt();

if (b <= a.length) {
System.out.println("Number Found");
break;
}
else {



System.out.println("Number Not Found");
}
}
}
}
```